# Angular star rating directive issue in Angular 1.4.7

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a little problem with star-rating directive.

Here is star-rating directive code and it is working perfectly in Angular 1.3.16 version but NOT working in Angular 1.4.7 version.

Acutually, It is still working in Angular 1.4.7 version, but keep reporting error **"TypeError: scope.onRatingSelected is not a function"**

```
 .directive("starRating", function() {
      return {
        restrict : "EA",
        template : "<ul class='rating' ng-class='{readonly: readonly}'>" +
                   "  <li ng-repeat='star in stars' ng-class='star' ng-click='toggle($index)'>" +
                   "    <i class='fa fa-star'></i>" + //&#9733
                   "  </li>" +
                   "</ul>",
        scope : {
          ratingValue : "=ngModel",
          max : "=?", //optional: default is 5
          onRatingSelected : "&?",
          readonly: "=?"
        },
        link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          if (scope.max == undefined) { scope.max = 5; }
          function updateStars() {
            scope.stars = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < scope.max; i++) {
              scope.stars.push({
                filled : (i < scope.ratingValue.rating)
              });
            }
          };
          scope.toggle = function(index) {
            if (scope.readonly == undefined || scope.readonly == false){
              scope.ratingValue.rating = index + 1;
              scope.onRatingSelected({
                rating: index + 1
              });
              scope.onRatingSelected()(index + 1);
            }
          };
          scope.$watch("ratingValue.rating", function(oldVal, newVal) {
            if (newVal) { updateStars(); }
          });
        }
      };  
    })
```

Comment: Well, to be fair, I do not see `onRatingSelected` defined anywhere? - Edit: I see it now. Are you passing it as a function to the directive?

Comment: where are you using the directive ? or in other words where and how is onRatingSelected implemented/defined ?

Comment: @HanletEscaño Can you please check this demo? http://codepen.io/TepigMC/pen/FIdHb

Comment: @PatrickKelleter I have a demo here http://codepen.io/TepigMC/pen/FIdHb

Comment: @KimCrab The demo is working fine for me. Is there something I am supposed to see here?